# Catch only a specific HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to aspx webforms.

I want to catch a specific Exception in my Web Application - `Validation of viewstate MAC failed`.
I tried this (in Global.asax.cs):

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpException lastErrWrapper = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

  if ((uint)lastErrWrapper.ErrorCode == 0x80004005)
  {
      // do something
  }         
}
```

The problem is that it catches all unhandled HttpExceptions.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

---

edit:

While checking this issue further I found that the inner exception is a `ViewStateException`, but it doesn't seem to have a specific "errorCode" attribute

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the other unhandled exceptions?

Comment: I believe that that casting may cause an exception itself. You should test like `if(Server.GetLastError() is HttpException){...}`

Comment: @MNGwinn - It doesn't really matter, I want to do a "different thing" then when it's the `Validation of viewstate MAC failed`

Comment: @AndreCalil- You're obviously correct, but this code is just an example. The problem is that **all** unhendled HttpExceptions are getting `ErrorCode == 0x80004005`, how can I distinguish between them?

Comment: @Bassal AFAIK, viewstate validation will throw a `HttpException`, so you can't distinguish it using only the error code. I'd test if it's a `HttpException` and if the message contains `validation`, `viewstate` and `MAC`.

Comment: For what it's worth, 0x80004005 is E_FAIL, the generic "this didn't work" COM HRESULT. You'll see this in lots of Exception.HResult properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it

```
if ((lastErrWrapper != null) && (lastErrWrapper.InnerException != null) 
  && (lastErrWrapper.InnerException is ViewStateException)
{
}
```

The HttpException is designed to make all the HTTP/web related stuff be catchable by one handler, so you need to dig in and look at the original exception. ViewStateException might catch a couple of other View State-related errors, but that's probably OK.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I found out too (see my edit). Is there no way to see which view state error was thrown ?

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to check all of the properties of the viewstateexception while debugging to see if any of them distinguish it.  Otherwise, you could just check the message of the exception for the specific "validation of viewstate mac failed".

Comment: The ErrorCode property on HttpException isn't inherited from Exception, and ViewStateException doesn't derive from HttpException, so I wouldn't expect to see it.  Docs say it contains an HRESULT, but that's normally in Exception.HResult. If you want to hope for a useful error code, you can check ViewStateException.HResult and see what's there.

Comment: Ugh. Comments don't take line breaks. Short version, you're not going to get far looking at ErrorCode and HResult properties. That's mostly there for legacy COM interoperability.

Comment: Thanks @MNGwinn, I guess that I'll use this solution and take it into consideration that this may catch some other view-state exceptions as well ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we have implemented to help counter ViewState errors in globa.asax:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim exception As Exception = Server.GetLastError

    'custom exception handling:
    If Not IsNothing(exception) Then

        If Not IsNothing(exception.InnerException) Then

            'ViewState Exception:
            If exception.InnerException.GetType = GetType(ViewStateException) Then
                'The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

                'Caused by VIEWSTATE|VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED|EVENTVALIDATION hidden fields being malformed
                ' + could be page is submitted before being fully loaded
                ' + hidden fields have been malformed by proxies or user tampering
                ' + hidden fields have been trunkated by mobile devices
                ' + remotly loaded content into the page using ajax causes the hidden fields to be overridden with incorrect values (when a user navigates back to a cached page)

                'Remedy: reload the request page to replenish the viewstate:
                Server.ClearError()
                Response.Clear()
                Response.Redirect(context.Request.Url.ToString, False)
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```